# How do I return an item when the type is read from file

Tags: c#

I am calling a function that has a type declared against the method, ie.

```
public T Get<T>().
```

I read in a string from a file and parse this through a switch to determine the type used, ie.

```
switch (type)
{
    case "Text":
         item = Get<Text>();
         break;
    case "Button":
         item = Get<Button>();
         break;
}
```

How would I then go about returning the item of Type  from the function where it was called? Note that I don't want to return a common parent as I need access to the methods of the derived class.

```
public <????> newGet()
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case "Text":
            item = Get<Text>();
            break;
        case "Button":
            item = Get<Button>();
            break;
    }
    return item;
}
```

Comment: You can't do that with generics. They're a compile-time only feature. You could use `dynamic`?

Comment: Thanks @Blorgbeard. This is the missing info I was after!

Comment: What types are `Text` and `Button`? Are those your types? If you defined them yourself, you can have them derive from a base type or implement a common interface, and then you can declare your return type as the common base type or interface and return either type of object.

Comment: I did not write the classes myself, I am using the MS UI Automation framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dynamic` sounds like a bad idea. You should reconsider what you're doing here.

"Note that I don't want to return a common parent as I need access to the methods of the derived class."

OK, so... you're going to do what to access these methods? Use another `switch` to switch between the types and then call the methods you want? Why are there two `switch` statements here doing the same thing? I don't know the exact architecture of what you're dealing with, but generally you'd be better off finding out what type you're going to be getting back (i.e. by returning "Text" or "Button" or whatever from a function) and then calling a strongly-typed function which goes and gets the thing and calls methods on it.

Comment: Thanks for the input @ChrisV. I planned to just do a "GetType" check whenever I used a method that was not common to all types (which will be rarely). I know that is a bit fiddly, but less so than doing this every time `Type t = newGetType(name);` `var item = newGet<t>(name);`. I just tried a quick demo in VS and it looks like you can't use Type as a return type anyway? This is only my second day on c# so please suggest any improvements

Comment: If you're mostly using methods of a common base class then return the object as the base class. If you want to use methods of a derived class, you can check type using `if(item is Type) { ... }`. This is better than `GetType` for your purposes. The `is` operator returns true for derived classes, so for an item of type `Dog`, `item is Animal` will be true while `typeof(item) == GetType(Animal)` will be false. So `item is Button` will be true if you're dealing with a subclass of `Button`, for instance.

Comment: Hi ChrisV, I don't see how using `if(item is Type) { ... }` will give me access to the derived classes methods. For example, `UIItem item = newGet(name);` `if(item is Button) { //I get here successfully, but I don't have access to Button.Press() }`

Comment: You just have to cast it after that, i.e. `Button btn = (Button)item;`. The `is` check is so you avoid an `InvalidCastException`. If you prefer, you could instead use `Button btn = item as Button;`. This will return `null` rather than throw an exception if item isn't a `Button`, so then you'll have to check for null instead. Amounts to the same thing.

Comment: Thanks! This was useful and is working a treat, sorry for all the questions =)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using the dynamic type. It's only available for .NET 4.0 and above

```
public dynamic newGet(string type)
{
   dynamic item = null;
   switch (type)
   {
      case "Text":
        item = "ABC";
        break;
      case "Number":
        item = 1;
        break;
   }
   return item;
}
```

As you can see, I can use the Length of the string returned from newGet

```
dynamic text= newGet("Text");
Console.WriteLine(text.Length); //"ABC".Length = 3

dynamic number= newGet("Number");
Console.WriteLine(number + 5); //1 + 5 = 6
```

This can also works. Just be careful of runtime exception

```
string text= newGet("Text"); //You can assign to
Console.WriteLine(text.Length); //"ABC".Length = 3

int number= newGet("Number");
Console.WriteLine(number + 5); //1 + 5 = 6
```